# Entity Framework Count and Group By in a Collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I have Lambda Expression that returns data properly filtered, but I need to do some calculations on the records returned.

I have two entities (User and Language) that have a many-to-many relationship and I need to make a grouped count of the returnees languages so that to find out how many people speak each returned language.

Sample set of data returned by the Lambda Expression:

- User1 (English, Spanish)
- User2 (English, French)
- User3 (English, Spanish)

Desired Result:

- English       3
- Spanish       2
- French        1

I tried to use the GroupBy () and select (), but only got the right result with a foreach over the results, but would like to do this using Lambda.

**[EDIT]**
The solution key was the results flattening using SelectMany () in combination with the GroupBy(). Thanks @Christos by point the right answer.

Comment: The relationship is `many-many` so each language should have some navigation property such as `Users`, so you can simply do something like `var langInfo = context.Languages.Select(e => new { Language = e, Count = e.Users.Count  }).ToList();`

Comment: I have to count and group just the elements contained in my original result. The coast to requery just for count is expensive.

Comment: You don't need to query all users to get its count, if you want to know how,  try googling for that or search for about ***explicit loading***. Of course before doing so the `lazy loading` should be disabled temporarily first. If you currently have just some loaded users, then follow the approach of the answer below (it's something like that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var results = data.SelectMany(user=>user.Languages)
                  .GroupBy(language=>language)
                  .Select(gr=>new { Language = gr.Key, Total = gr.Count()});
```

I have **supposed** that each user object has a sequence of strings, `IEnumerable<string>`, which is called languages and holds the user's languages. Furthermore, the data you have is sequence of all the users.

Comment: As matter of fact the Languages are a collection of Language (IEnumerable<Language>). Anyway, I guess I can adapt your answer. I'll test it. Tks

Comment: Just a small correction: the Key and Count are from the gr and not from the language. Tks! Correcting this, worked like a charm.

Comment: @Douglas Gandini you are correct ! Thank you very much for spotting this.  You are welcome. I am glad that I helped.